# How to use if then if then else condition in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have a condition in Excel

[image: As seen in image]

If the type is incident and is closed on or before 4 days next column should populate "Met", else "Not Met"
Also,

If the type is request and is closed on or before 14 days next column should populate "Met", else "Not Met"

I want both these conditions clubbed.

Is it possible to create a button using VB that will automate this process?

Comment: yes it is possible

Comment: It's definitely possible with VBA, but would probably be a lot easier for you with a nested `IF` statement.  Here's a link to get you started: https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/if_nested.php .  What's a clubbed condition? Sounds like something better suited to https://health.stackexchange.com/ .

Comment: any luck with that?  *fine*

Comment: @ashleedawg I think a hitman for the clubbing is missing :-) Apologies Rohan for the humour.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need for VBA:

[image: screenshot]

I'd suggest you look up the three functions I used.

Answer (score 0):

Use the formula :

```
=IF(A2="incident",IF(B2<=4,"Met","Not Met"),IF(A2="request",IF(B2<=14,"Met","Not Met")))
```

Then drag the formula in rest of the cells in the column.

[image: Screenshot is attached herewith]

You can also check out my tutorial on using IF in MS Excel at Youtube : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ONhAToWVc1E